# How is a rvalue dereferenced?

Tags: c++, dereference, lvalue, rvalue

> The prefix operators return the object
>   itself as an lvalue. The postfix operators return a copy of the object’s original value
>   as an rvalue.

so in a statement like so `*a++` a is being incremented and a copy of the original value of a is returned as rvalue but from the microsoft c++ language reference on Lvalues and Rvalues

> An rvalue is a temporary value that does not persist beyond the expression that uses it

and gives an example

```
// lvalues_and_rvalues1.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int x = 3 + 4;
   cout << x << endl;
}
```

> In this example, x is an lvalue because it persists beyond the expression that defines it. The expression 3 + 4 is an rvalue because it evaluates to a temporary value that does not persist beyond the expression that defines it.

My questions:
1) what is the rvalue being returned from the `*a++` so that it can be dereferenced?
2) Did i misunderstand any concept ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first quote is false, e.g. `+x` is an rvalue.  Maybe it is only talking about the `++` and `--` operators.

Comment: @M.M i don't think so it is exactly what primer c++ says

Comment: The second quote is also wrong: *rvalue* is an expression category, not a value.  (Slightly confusing naming).  `3 + 4` is an rvalue, but the third quote should say "it does not persist beyond the expression because it is a temporary value"  , not the other way around.

Comment: @M.M https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/f90831hc.aspx you can verify it there

Comment: I mean the quote is factually incorrect - wasn't accusing you of mis-transcribing or anything

Comment: I don't understand your Question 1, could you rephrase it or give an example of what you are talking about

Comment: @M.M I believe psrag is referring specifically to prefix/postfix increment/decrement operators.  `+x` is an rvalue, but `++x` is an lvalue.  Although if anyone ever codes `++x = 10;` they should be shot.

Comment: @psraganvesh: Can you please clarify question #1? It's impossible to answer this otherwise.

Comment: I edited the first question.

Comment: (Assuming `a` is a pointer), The value of `a++` is a pointer. `*` can be applied to pointers and it yields the object being pointed to.

Comment: [Here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) is a page that describes what *rvalue* means .. no surprise you are confused if you tried to learn from thet MSDN page

Comment: `*(a+0)` would be a similar case

Comment: @M.M Yes rvalues are a bit confusing to me i am assuming rvalue that is returned is a integer literal and as so it cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: rvalues can have any type   . `3 + 4` has type `int`, but `a++` has type `int *`

Comment: @M.M so they can have a type but not "represents an object that occupies some identifiable location in memory"

Comment: @psraganvesh Yes that is one way to put it.  But bear in mind that for rvalues of class type (i.e. rvalues that designate temporary objects), you can obtain an lvalue that identifies the location of that temporary object. (E.g. if the object has a member function that does `return *this;` by reference).   The rvalue-ness is a property of the expression, not of the object.  Say "temporary object" if you mean temporary object.

Comment: @M.M Thanks for your time!

Comment: @M.M I agree: I gave up searching for information from MSDN years ago; that is why I have been a loyal member to this community since I've discovered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The prefix operators return the object itself as an lvalue. The postfix operators return a copy of the object’s original value as an rvalue.

**Wrong!** Well, mostly. If the quote is talking about *all* prefix/suffix operators, then it's completely errated. However, if it's talking about the `++` and `--` prefix/postfix pairs, then it's correct.

Now, taking that into account...

> what is the rvalue returning from the *a++ so that it can be dereferenced?

Assuming `a` is a pointer of some kind, `a++` increments `a` and yields a rvalue consisting of `a`'s value before the increment. The increment and decrement operators, `++` and `--`, in both postfix and prefix forms, require an lvalue as their operator. This is because rvalues are temporary, that is, their scope is limited by the expression their occur in, so these operators make little or no sense on them. Remember, these operators not only *inspect*/*read*, but *change*/*write to* the variable itself.

The unary `*` operator takes a pointer(-like) object and dereferences it, yielding an lvalue found in there. It works for both rvalue and lvalue pointers. This is because `*` can be considered sort of a "passive" operator. It does not *change*/*write to* the pointer itself, but dereferences it and returns the lvalue object at the address stored by the pointer, whose address is of course that contained by the pointer. As all that `*` needs is the memory address contained in a pointer object, and the address of the pointer itself, if it has one at all, is useless here, `*` makes sense for both rvalues and lvalues.

You can think that `*` "requires an rvalue", and that "lvalues can be used as rvalues when necessary", if it clarifies (or confuses?) things a little bit more.

Comment: so the a's value before the increment is a memory location so as long as '*' has a memory location either lvalue(object with memory location) or rvalue( expression that does not represent an object occupying some identifiable location in memory.) it can be dereferenced to get the value stored in the address

Comment: @psraganvesh: Exactly.

Comment: Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

`*a++` is equivalent to:

```
auto temp = *a;
a++;
// Use the value of temp here
```

except you can only refer to the value once, where as `temp` you could refer to multiple times.

Comment: well this is true but I don't think it addresses OP's question (which seems to be: why can `*` be applied to an rvalue).

Comment: True.  `a` could be a pointer, or it could be an object of any class that overloads `operator *`.  But if the question is "Why can `*` be applied to `a++`?", the answer has to be "Because `*` could be applied to `a`."

Comment: @JamesRoot No.  The postfix `++` operator increments the value of `a` __after__ it has been used.  Here, using it is dereferencing it with the `*` operator.  So the order is `*a`, then `a++`.

Comment: True, but `a` is an lvalue and `a++` is an rvalue, and OP seems to think there are different rules for applying `*` to each of those categories